# Capability name ' java_home' is not valid

Tags: azure-devops, agent

I am trying to configuring the local agent in my local pc, at that time I got the below error.

> Capability name ' java_home' is not valid. Capability names must be
>   less than 256 characters in length and may not start or end with
>   whitespace characters

.

In the below I am posting the screenshot what the error I got when I am configuring the VSTSAgent in my PC

[image]

Can you please suggest me how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: What's the value of Java_Home variable? Try to remove it and setup/configure agent, after that, add the variable again and restart build agent. (remove whitespace characters at the end if has.)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it.

Your `java_home` environment variable has a leading space character. Fix that.

Comment: There is no spaces in my java_home environment variable I am placing its correctly and again I am getting the same thing only

Comment: @sateesh The screenshot you provided indicated that there is a blank space. Can you check it?